# "Тараканы" в голове. Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки:

**"Тараканы" в голове: как с ними бороться?**

Comment: @Charmante_K, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Вполне приемлемый вариант: "Тараканы в голове": как с ними бороться?

Выражение очень известное, поэтому использование кавычек необходимо там, где желательно обозначить его условность.

Но часто пишут без кавычек, например: У каждого в голове свои тараканы.

Аналоги этой фразы в других языках: в немецком существует выражение : «einen Vogel im Kopf haben», которое переводится как «иметь птицу в голове»; английский вариант: «a bee in one’s bonnet»,  «пчела в шляпе». В этих примерах уж точно нужны кавычки.